# Change CSS property on each page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class, navigation, menuitem

I'm trying to make a navigation menu for a website. The hover event (jQuery) changes `<div>`background position so a user can see where he is pointing. The final effect I want to achieve looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WAckU/

The problem with this solution is that when I click on `<li>` (page changes) I loose the variable (background position resets) So I wonder if there is any workaround, maybe just adding CSS class to the element I click on (similar to some Wordpress themes)? 
I'd also like to avoid persisting the value by cookies.

Comment: This depends on what the backend of your website is capable of. Wordpress runs on PHP which has a set of tools to assign an "active" class to an element dependent on what was clicked, as do other technologies. There's no way to persist between two pages with normal javascript without the use of Ajax, Json and/or Cookies.

Comment: ah, forgot to mention. I can use PHP ofcourse.

Comment: You can always of course fake it on static pages as well by just adding the class to the active element in the HTML or setting it jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the current page in window.location.href, and set background image initially depending on it

```
var currentpage = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
switch(currentpage){
    case "page1.php": $(".topmenu").css('background-position', position1);break;
    case "page2.php": $(".topmenu").css('background-position', position2);break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just initialise the variable to the value you want on each page? Or if you dont want to make exceptions, get the js to look at the url to figure out where it is.

Comment: page consist of several sections(its build on eCommerce system) so I don't now if making a variable for each page would be smart. Checking the url seems like a much better option. Thx, gonna try to find more about it.